# Will large transaction log file slow db recovery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Did a manual failover after windows updates to passive node today and recovery was fast for all but one db. The one slow db had a transaction log size of 203200.00 mb. Log Space percent used = 0.25.  Will the large transaction log file size slow down recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but if there was a large transaction running at the time of failover that could cause both a large log file and a slow failover.